# Prove that set $M=\lbrace(-\infty, r] : r \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$ generates Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

How can you prove that set $M=\lbrace(-\infty, r] : r \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$ generates Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$?

I cannot see how to construct a sets of the form $(a,b)$, ie open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, just from unions of $(-\infty,r] \in M$. I dont think the empty set will help much.

Is it possible to use intersections in my solution? If so what type of intersection can I use?

For your information my definition of the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}$ , is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. I realise that this definition also works if we replace "open" by "closed".

Does $\lbrace(-\infty, r) : r \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$ generate Borel sigma algebra as well?

Comment: Hint: First show that $(-\infty,r]$ can be expressed as a countable union of Borel sets. Then show that any open set can be expressed as a countable union of sets of the form $(-\infty,r]$

Comment: You mean countable intersections of sets of the form $(-\infty,r]$? I cannot construct a set $(-3,4)$ from unions of $(-\infty,r]$.

Comment: Use that if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$

Comment: @user4205580 You're right. We will need a combination of unions and/or intersections (which are allowed by the definition of sigma algebras).

Comment: @1234 Probably because it lacks efforts of the OP himself to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume that your definition of the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}$ , is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Remember first that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then if  $A \in \mathcal{A} \implies A^c \in \mathcal{A}$.

Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the collection of all open intervals. Since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is at most a countable union of open intervals, we get that $\sigma(\mathcal{O})=\mathcal{B}$.

Now each $\displaystyle (a,b)= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{ (-\infty, b-\frac{1}{n} ] \cap (-\infty,a+\frac{1}{n}]^c\}$

which implies that $(a,b) \in \sigma(M)$. That is $\mathcal{O} \subset \sigma(M)$, so $\sigma(\mathcal{O})\subset \sigma(M)$. Also, every element of M is a closed set so $\sigma(M) \subset \mathcal{B}$.

Therefore we get that $\mathcal{B} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{O}) \subset \sigma(M) \subset \mathcal{B}$, and the result follows.

1) PROPOSITION. If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is stable under countable intersection.

PROOF. $$\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i = \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i^c \right)^c$$

so stability follows from stability of countable union and complementation.

2) Note that if $a_n = a+\frac{1}{n}$, $a_n \downarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and if $a_n = b-\frac{1}{n}$, $b_n \uparrow b$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: That looks better, I will delete my former comment.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ be $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$?

Comment: If not, I don't understand why $(a,b) = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$.

Comment: @user4205580 I think thats about as much as I can help you.

Comment: What I'm asking is why are you summing up intervals $\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ instead of $\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$. If you don't want to include a and b, then it should be $[$ on the left if you used $]$ on the right. Now there's asymmetry because you use $($ on the left and $]$ on the right, and I don't know why.

Comment: $(a,b)= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ is really just an intermediary step to the next inequality

Comment: Do you understand the notation $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20001/discussion-between-1234-and-user4205580).

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ then $\mathcal{B}=\sigma\left(\tau\right)$ where $\tau$ denotes
the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

If we can show $\tau\subseteq\sigma\left(M\right)$ then we are ready,
because $\sigma\left(\tau\right)\subseteq\sigma\left(M\right)$ follows directly.

The topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable basis of open intervals
$\left(a,b\right)$ so that every open set can be written as a countable
union of such intervals. This tells us that it is enough to prove
that every open interval  $\left(a,b\right)$ is an element of $\sigma\left(M\right)$.

Note that $\left(-\infty,b\right)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\infty,b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$
showing that $\left(-\infty,b\right)\in\sigma\left(M\right)$.

I leave the rest up to you.